# Dehumidifier problem

Tags: electrical

I live in a apartment. It is not insulated. The outside is block because it was converted into a apartment from the end of a garage. I heat with a ventless gas heater. In the winter I have so much moisture that my indoor window seals drip with water. The closet had ice on the inside. My clothes smell musty. I’ve got a dehumidifier and what do I need to set the RH% on in order to keep the moisture removed.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where are you located, and is there any chance to vent that heater outside (it's the source of most of your moisture)? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

You have a ventless gas heater problem. I would strongly suggest using a vented (preferably 
"sealed combustion" with an outside air intake as well as an exhaust) rather than a ventless heater which dumps combustion byproducts, including a great deal of water vapor into your living space.

You can set a dehumidifer at 50%, and it will probably help, if it keeps up with the problem (i.e has adequate capacity), but it's treating the effect, rather than the cause.

Or use a cold-climate air-air mini-split heat pump, which may be cost competitive with gas heat depending on your local gas and electric rates, and which also will not dump water into your air.

Comment: Specifically, you risk carbon monoxide buildup, as well as moisture!

Comment: Electric heaters are great.  Probably you need to switch.  Your dehumidifier will definitely be equal to the humidity you yourself exhale.